# Max size/ length of Varchar and Varchar2 for different databases

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

Is the size limit of VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 different across the various SQL RDBMS implementations or is it the same? Thanks for help.

Comment: AFAIK `varchar2` is Oracle-specific so I'm not sure what the question is. The size limit of `varchar` depends on the database though.

Comment: Are you asking this out of curiosity or is there a reason?

Comment: I am asking to know, weather VARCHAR or VARCHAR2 have different size limit in different databases or the size limit is same across all the databases?

Comment: @user1716079 - But *WHY?* Are you migrating data between them or what?

Comment: What are you migration *from* and what *to*?

Comment: Different OS, same database it’s going to be same or will it be vary?

Comment: Same database...? why then are you asking if it varies between databases???

Comment: Different OS, same database it’s going to be same or will it be vary?

Comment: From the below mentioned i got to know that VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 may be vary from one database to another but my further question is if database is same but we are using different OS. For example say..Oracle  in window and Oracle in linux. Will it crate any variance in size limit of VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 ?

Comment: @user1716079 - It should not matter from OS to OS as long as it is the same RDBMS. You really should work on asking less vague questions...

Answer (score 5):

First of all `varchar` is used in MySQL and `varchar2` is used in Oracle.
Moreover, size and limits of varchar and varchar2 differs across databases.

Reference from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm

> MySQL and Oracle have some differences in the character types that
>   they support and in the way they store and retrieve the character type
>   values.
>
> MySQL supports the CHAR and VARCHAR type for character type with a
>   length that is less than 65,535 bytes. The CHAR type can have a
>   maximum length of 255 bytes, and as of MySQL 3.23 it may also be
>   declared with a length of 0 byte. Before MySQL 5.0.3, the length
>   specification for the VARCHAR type is the same as the CHAR type. From
>   MySQL 5.0.3 on, the maximum length for the VARCHAR type is 65,535
>   bytes. Oracle supports four character types: CHAR, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2
>   and VARCHAR2. The minimum length that can be declared for all Oracle
>   character types is 1 byte. The maximum size allowed for CHAR and NCHAR
>   is 2,000 bytes, and for NVARCHAR2 and VARCHAR2 it is 4,000 bytes.
>
> MySQL CHAR values are right-padded with spaces to the specified length
>   when they are stored, and trailing spaces are removed when the values
>   are retrieved. On the other hand, VARCHAR values are stored using as
>   many characters as are given, but before MySQL 5.0.3 trailing spaces
>   are removed when the values are stored and retrieved. Oracle
>   blank-pads the value for its CHAR and NCHAR type to the column length
>   if the value is shorter than the column length, and trailing spaces
>   are not removed on retrieval. For NVARCHAR2 and VARVHAR2 data type
>   columns, Oracle stores and retrieves the value exactly as is given,
>   including trailing spaces.
>
> If a value is assigned to a character type column that exceeds its
>   specified length, MySQL truncates the value and does not generate an
>   error unless the STRICT SQL mode is set. Oracle generates an error if
>   the value assigned to a character type column exceeds its specified
>   length.
>
> In MySQL, every character type (CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT) column has a
>   column character set and collation. If the character set or collation
>   is not explicitly defined in the column definition, the table
>   character set or collation is implied if specified; otherwise, the
>   database character or collation is chosen. In Oracle, the character
>   set for CHAR and VARCHAR2 types is defined by the database character
>   set, and for the character set for NCHAR and NVARCHAR types is defined
>   the national character set.
>
> When declaring a CHAR or VARCHAR type in MySQL, the default length
>   semantics is characters instead of bytes for MySQL 4.1 and later. In
>   Oracle, the default length semantics is bytes for CHAR and VARCHAR2
>   types and characters for NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 types.
>
> SQL Developer will map MySQL CHAR and VARCHAR types to Oracle CHAR and
>   VARCHAR2 types, respectively. SQL Developer will determine the maximum
>   number of bytes for the Oracle CHAR and VARCHAR2 data type columns
>   from the number of bytes required to hold the maximum length specified
>   for the corresponding MySQL CHAR and VARCHAR data type columns. If the
>   MySQL VARCHAR2 column is such that the data exceeds 4000 bytes,
>   convert the column to an Oracle CLOB data type column.

Comment: but different OS, same database it’s going to be same or will it be vary?

Comment: @user1716079 - That is not what your question was asking....

Comment: From the above mentioned i got to know that VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 may be vary from one database to another but my further question is if database is same but we are using different OS. For example say..Oracle  in window and Oracle in linux. Will it crate any variance in size limit of VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 ?

Comment: In MySQL changing OS doesn't changes limit for VARCHAR and CHAR. To be very honest, I do not have much exposure of Oracle and other DBs, so cant comment on them.

Comment: Only VARCHAR works perfectly for MySQL, VARCHAR2 doesn't works good for MySQL it gives error. Both VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 works perfectly for Oracle ,for example :- mysql> create table emp3(empid int(3),empname varchar2(20),empsal int(10),empcity varchar2(10), empcompany varchar2(10));